# replace 3 levels of nested for loops by efficient code possibly linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way of replacing following 3 levels of nested for-loops into more efficient or cleaner code? Would linq be able to make it more efficient and easy to read?

Please help. Thanks

```
bool myMatch = false;

foreach (MyEntityClass entitySmallerSet in entitiesSmallerSet)
{
    if (entityLargerSet.Key.Equals(entitySmallerSet.Key))
    {
        foreach (var stringResValLarge in entityLargerSet.StringResourceValues)
        {
            foreach (var stringResValSmall in entitySmallerSet.StringResourceValues)
            {
                if (stringResValSmall.Culture.Equals(stringResValLarge.Culture)
                    && stringResValSmall.Value.Equals(stringResValLarge.Value))
                {
                    myMatch = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition for entityLargerSet?

Comment: No formatting, no context, just garbage...

Comment: Are we solving your homeworks? :p

Comment: this is related to my work.. I have been asked to make it more efficient but I don't know how to.

Comment: Nested looping over sets looks to me as if you could achieve better runtime performance by keeping your data in different data structures. A `Dictionary<Tuple<Culture, T>, IEnumerable<MyEntityClass>>` for each entity for instance, where `T` is the type of `Value`. What do you think (it's just an idea)?

Comment: LB, I corrected the format.. can you please not down vote my question.. this is a valid question.. If I knew, how to solve, I would not be asking here. SO is becoming a very difficult place to ask questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
bool myMatch = entitiesSmallerSet
    .Where(e => entityLargerSet.Key.Equal(e.Key))
    .SelectMany(e => e.StringResourceValues)
    .Join(entityLargerSet.StringResourceValues, small => new { Culture = small.Culture, Value = small.Value }, large => new { Culture = large.Culture, Value = large.Value }, (s, l) => new object())
    .Any();
```

Instead of the join you can use `Intersect`:

```
bool myMatch = entitiesSmallerSet
    .Where(e => entityLargerSet.Key.Equal(e.Key))
    .SelectMany(e => e.StringResourceValues)
    .Select(e => new { Culture = e.Culture, Value = e.Value })
    .Intersect(entityLargerSet.StringResourceValues.Select(l => new { Culture = l.Culture, Value = l.Value }))
    .Any();
```

Comment: +1 for this as it is very elegant, plus it breaks as soon as one match is found. The original solution loops over and over again, even when `match` has been `true` for long.

Comment: Lee, thanks for the answer.. how would I identify the entityLargerSet which is missing from the entitiesSmallerSet?

Answer (score 0):

Resharper does this with it:

```
    bool myMatch = false;
    foreach ( var stringResValLarge in 
    from entitySmallerSet 
    in entitiesSmallerSet.Where(entitySmallerSet => entityLargerSet.Key.Equals( entitySmallerSet.Key )) 
    from stringResValLarge in entityLargerSet 
    from stringResValSmall in entitySmallerSet 
    where stringResValSmall.Equals( stringResValLarge )&& stringResValSmall.Equals( stringResValLarge ) 
    select stringResValLarge )
    {
      myMatch = true;
    }
```

(had to remove some of the dot props to get resharper to do it's thing. )

Comment: @Eonasdan I am not supposed to format the answer/question to make it more readible. If someone asks/answers, he/she should show his/her best effort to format it.

Comment: @L.B I wasn't suggesting that you should. My comment was meant to indicate I was surprised someone would down vote just for formatting, until I scrolled the answer. I, however, would have simply edited it.

Comment: @Eonasdan Why should I edit it? Just to make other one's work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this idea (pseudocode):

```
var myMatch = (from se in entitiesSmallerSet
               where e.Key.Equals(entitySmallerSet.Key)
               from seVal in se.StringResourceValues
               from leVal in entityLargerSet.StringResourceValues
               where seVal.Culture.Equals(leVal.Culture)
                  && leVal.Value.Equals(leVal.Value)
               select seVal).Any();
```