# convert multi level for loop into linq or lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I already posted related question as follows:

[replace 3 levels of nested for loops by efficient code possibly linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923220/replace-3-levels-of-nested-for-loops-by-efficient-code-possibly-linq)

But since I am not good with Linq or Lambda expression.. I am not sure how to further expand on it.

I have a slightly different 3 level nested for loop that I don't know how to transfer it into Linq or Lambda expression.. I have been tasked at work to come up with more efficient replacement code for the following in linq or lambda expression .. Please help. thanks..

```
public static void CompareEntities(
    out EntityCollection<StringResourceEntity> entitiesDifference,
    EntityCollection<StringResourceEntity> entitiesLargerSet,
    EntityCollection<StringResourceEntity> entitiesSmallerSet)
{
    var diff = new EntityCollection<StringResourceEntity>();
    string defaultCulture = LocalizationConfiguration.DefaultCulture;

    foreach (StringResourceEntity entityLargerSet in entitiesLargerSet)
    {
        bool entityMatch = false;
        foreach (StringResourceEntity entitySmallerSet in entitiesSmallerSet)
        {
            if (entityLargerSet.Key.Equals(entitySmallerSet.Key))
            {
                foreach (var stringResValSmall in entitySmallerSet.StringResourceValues)
                {
                    if (stringResValSmall.Culture.Equals(defaultCulture) &&
                        stringResValSmall.Value.Length > 0)
                    {
                        entityMatch = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (entityMatch == false)
        {
            diff.Add(entityLargerSet);
        }
    }

    entitiesDifference = diff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I much prefer lambda expressions as I find them very readable. I'd do something like this:

```
var diff = entitiesLargerSet.Where(large => 
    !entitiesSmallerSet.Any(small => 
        small.Key.Equals(large.Key) 
        && small.StringResourceValues.Any(x => 
            x.Culture.Equals(defaultCulture) && x.Value.Length > 0))).ToList();
```

The indentation is horrible but make it your own.

Comment: Kirk, very cool answer.. thanks a million.. I will go back and hit the books and make sure that I understand this and build on it. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started. Without creating skeleton versions of all your classes it's a bit hard to tell whether the code compiles properly or will yield the correct result:

```
var diff = entitiesLargerSet.Except(
            from x in entitiesLargerSet
            from y in entitiesSmallerSet
            where x.Key.Equals(y.Key)
            from z in y.StringResourceValues
            where stringResValSmall.Culture.Equals(defaultCulture)
               && stringResValSmall.Value.Length > 0
            select x);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.. this may only find all the matches.. I am looking for records that do not match.. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
string defaultCulture = LocalizationConfiguration.DefaultCulture;
var diff = (from x in entitiesLargerSet
            let matches = entitiesSmallerSet.Where(y =>
                 x.Key.Equals(y.Key) &&
                 y.StringResourceValues.Any( z => z.Culture.Equals(defaultCulture) &&
                                                  z.Value.Length > 0))
            where matches.Any() == false
            select x).ToList();
// TODO: Convert List to EntityCollection
```

Comment: Thanks Risky... I really like your answer but I am going to check Kirk's answer. thank you again!!